# Is it compulsory to set up Gitlab server and a Gitlab runner configured?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

As per the Gitlab CI(version 8.0) documentations and blogs I was red I came to the conclusion that I need to setup Gitlab server  and a Gitlab runner on VM/docker etc. Correct me if I am wrong

I am very new to continuous integration concept. Please anyone let me know is it compulsory to setup Runner on Virtual Machine or do we  have any alternative way to use Gitlab CI without Runner. Sorry if this question is silly.

Please guide me from where would I start if anyone have the nice documentation to setup and use Gitlab CI end to end. Thanks and very much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a runner, but if you want to do CI you do need one. That is basicly it. Ofcourse you can also still do on commit to trigger jenkins or anything else and create that kind of CI. It all depends what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the replay @Erik. I want to do CI. As per the GitLab architecture (https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/) I see one GitLab server(Hope I must setup this) and Runners (It can be my personal computer).

Comment: I am going to use GitLab CI by the way not Jenkins. Now I had setup GitLab CI on EC2 instance successfully with test repo. Next step is to concentrate on how to work with Runners. Please correct me if I am on right track. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

No you don't need to setup your own VM to use Runners (specific Runners). GitLab also provides shared Runners, which can be used by anyone. Read about the difference [here](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/README.html).

---

There are four short steps to use GitLab Runners:

1. Enable a shared Runner tagged with docker under `Project > Runners`
2. Specify a regular expression under `Project > CI/CD Pipelines > Test coverage parsing` to filter coverage from console output
3. Create a docker image containing everything needed to build and test your project
4. Create `.gitlab-ci.yml` in your project’s root and define how testing/coverage is to be done

You can see some examples [here](http://quaintous.com/2016/08/12/test-and-code-coverage-with-gitlab-ci/). (*disclaimer*: article is written by me)

Comment: Thanks. I used to follow the same. When I was the beginner, it took more time to understand the logic behind gitlab ci runners.

Comment: @NagarjunaDN it also took me a while to get a grip of it :)